# Alias for echo function with espeak executed in background

Tags: bash, echo, alias, espeak

I want to replace the normal `echo` function in ubuntu bash with a function that additionally uses espeak to say something everytime `echo` is used.

I came up with an alias for my `.bashrc`

```
alias ghostTalk='espeak -v +whisper -s 80 -p 100 "$(myFun)"& /bin/echo $1'
```

(in my final version I would replace `ghostTalk` with `echo`)

But this gives as output:

```
~$ ghostTalk 123
[2] 5685
123
[1]   Done                    espeak -v +whisper -s 80 -p 100 "$(myFun)"
```

How can I avoid this and have the normal `echo` output e.g. only `123` while its talking in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backgrounding notifications can be suppressed with a double-fork:

```
ghostTalk() {
  ( espeak -v +whisper -s 80 -p 100 "$(myFun)" & )
  builtin echo "$@"
}
```